# Django choking on special character in model name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using a legacy MSSQL database with my Django application, and one of the column names contains a "%".  As a result, Django is looking for a format variable whenever the model is called.

I've isolated the issue to know it breaks on this field within my model:

```
fg_field = models.DecimalField(db_column="FG%", max_digits=15...
```

And the error message I get is:

```
sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params)) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

When I note out this field in the model, the application works fine... so I know it has to do with this naming convention.

Can I do anything on the Django side to stop this from happening?

Comment: The problem is that the `%` character is later used when *generating a Query*: it is seen as a string formatter. I woulld really advice to remove it. You can try double percentage `%%`, but the odds are likely that it will fail somewhere.

Comment: That being said, I think you can file a ticket to the Django project to change this, such that it is supported in the way you provide it.

Comment: It is rather sad, since this could perhaps get exploited for SQL injection (although I can not immediately come up with a scenario, it *could* perhaps result in a security vulnerability)

Comment: i am not an mssql expert but i could have sworn that the % character isn't allowed in table names. It certainly isn't allowed in any of the officially supported databases. MSSQL on the other hand isn't officially supported. Support is available only through third party backends.